# How can I make the cross-env and nodemon work together?

Tags: npm, package.json

This is my package.json fragment.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development run-p server start",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server", 
    "server":"nodemon -r dotenv/config ./server/index.js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
```

When I execute the following command:

```
npm run dev
```

The nodemon working properly.

However, when I execute the following command:

```
npm run prod
```

The nodemon seems to be not working. When I change the content of ./server/index.js, the file is not reloaded.

It works when changing the following statement:

```
"prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
```

to

```
"prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon -r dotenv/config ./server/index.js",
```

However, I don't want to duplicate the following phase:

```
"nodemon -r dotenv/config ./server/index.js".
```

So, would you tell me how I can make it work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `nodemon.json` config file.
For example:

#### nodemon.json

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts, js, json",
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node -T"
  }
}
```

and into the `package.json` you call `nodemon` normally. For example:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon ./src/server.ts",
  }
}
```

This is an usage example with `typescript` but you can readjust to `nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution.

```
"scripts": {
     ..........    
     "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development run-p server start",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject",
     "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run server", 
     "server":"nodemon -r dotenv/config ./server/index.js",
     ..........    
 },
```